# Spring-Boot @Async: How to figure out actual method name annotation with @Async at runtime?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-async, spring-boot-2

I need to figure out the @Async method name in TaskDecorator.  How do I figure out the method name (asyncMethodWithReturnType) from TaskDecorator or I there a better way to figure out the actual method that is annotated with @Async  in Spring Boot 2?

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor th =  new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    // HERE AUDIT WOULD collect metric about method name.
    th.setTaskDecorator(runnable -> AuditWrapper.auditWrapper(runnable)) 
 
}

@Async
public Future<String> asyncMethodWithReturnType() {
    System.out.println("Execute method asynchronously - " 
      + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return new AsyncResult<String>("hello world !!!!");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //
    }

    return null;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any better suggestions to find out the actual method being executed. I need to collect method name for an audit/metics purpose.

Comment: Why do you need the method name? Instead of using a task decorator you might be better of using AOP for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thank you for responding.  Can you please elaborate on how I can use AOP ?  AOP must run the thread that does work (invoke a method).  if you could be kind to provide one sample or example or pointer that would be a great help!

Comment: @M.Deinum, I was able to achieve this via AOP and pointcut is running on executed work. Thanks for your suggestion and help!